# An explicit conversion during while passing arguments

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My method takes

```
params Expression<Func<TEntity, IQueryable<TEntity>>>[] included
```

as parametres. And later uses them in this way:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
    if(included!=null)
    {
        foreach(var z in included)
        {
            query.Include(z);
        }
    }
```

however I'm not able to call this function because of an error thrown in this call:

```
Get(w=>w.Device, w=>w.DeviceUsage));
```

> Error 10  Cannot implicitly convert type 'magazyn.Models.Device' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How to modify call to pass those two params?

Comment: You `Device` or `DeviceUsage` property is not an `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your included expressions should be of type `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` - they are used to select included navigation *property* from entity you are querying:

```
params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] included
```

Also keep in mind, that when you are not passing expressions to your method, then array of params will not be null - it will be empty. So you can skip null-check

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

foreach(var path in included)
    query = query.Include(path);
```

Comment: Thanks but one more question. TProperty is what? I can see no such type in my project

Comment: @szpic sorry, my bad. It should be non-generic `object` type instead of generic `TProperty`. Also don't forget to assign included query back to query